How to Keep HTML and TS in sync?
Say I have in HTML:
<div id="foo"></div>

and then in TS something like:
const el = document.getElementById("foo")

Is there a way I can check at compile time that foo exists as a valid id in the HTML?
For example, I can ensure that the TS and the back-end data structures stay in sync using something like openapi-typescript to generate a .d.ts file containing back-end type information.
But is there some equivalent library to ensure the TS and HTML stay in sync? Is there some equivalent solution I can use to generate a myhtmlfile.d.ts containing valid ids and such so I can detect at compile time if my HTML has gotten out of sync with the TS?

Nope, can’t check at compile time. Keep in mind the user (or external libraries or browser extensions) can alter the DOM independent of your program

Consider using a UI framework with data binding.  There are many.

These types of assurances can be realized by testing your code (e.g. when you compile).

I don't think it would be too hard to parse the HTML and generate a list of ids or other DOM types into a .d.ts file on .html save. I guess there's not a big market for that tool though because of the prevalence of UI frameworks (which I am avoiding because I tend to stick to vanilla)

Ok, it's intresting. I never thought of it as a problem.
As far as I know, there's no toolkit that does this out of the box (except for framework templateizers, but that's different).
I wrote the following script in JS:
function generateTypeDefinitions(htmlPath, outputPath) {
    const htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(htmlPath, 'utf-8');
    const dom = new JSDOM(htmlContent);

    const ids = [...dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('[id]')].map(element => element.id);

    const typeDefinitions = ids.map(id => `declare const ${id}: HTMLElement;`).join('\n');

    fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, typeDefinitions);
}


Sorry, it doesn't take into account a lot of nuances, but in general it reflects my idea. You can add a similar script into your build system to generate .d.ts files that will display all the id's (or whatever else you need for you). In addition, you will have to configure your build system to keep track of the generated style files. This way you will be able to type the html.
Usage method:
const htmlFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');
const outputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'types/html.d.ts');

generateTypeDefinitions(htmlFilePath, outputFilePath);

